# How to understand None, [ ], [1] in python?

Tags: python

I am now confused by the output of block 1, 2 and 3, what's the relationship among them?
[image: output of some code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will update all these False-equivalent codes from now on.

Conclusions:

It's Sunday, March 24, 2019.

- `NaN` is not False-equivalent because `print(float('NaN') and False)` gives `False`

---

(It's Tuesday, March 19, 2019.)

- `-1` is not False-equivalent because the result of

  `print(-1 and False)`

  is `False`.
- `not 1, [], None, 0` are False-equivalent because the results of

  `print(not -1)
  print([] and False)
  print(None and False)
  print(0 and False)`

  are `False, [], None, 0`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If you have `A and B` and `A` is evaluated to some False equivalent, the expression will simply return `A` (which is False or equivalent) and skipped `B`. But if `A` is True equivalent, we return the value of `B` because `A` doesn't matter anymore for the value of the whole expression.

Similarly for the case of `or`, if we have `A or B` and `A` is True equivalent, `B` will be skipped and `A` is returned for the expression. Or, if `A` is False equivalent, `B` is returned.

Comment: What is False equivalent, including `[ ]`, `0`, `None`, and negative numbers such as `-1`, `-2`?

Comment: Empty containers (lists, dictionaries, strings, etc.), the number zero, and `None` are false.  Non-empty containers and nonzero numbers are true.

Comment: In numbers False is only equivalent to 0 because that's its value, 1 is the value of True so things like False + 2 will return 2

Comment: @JohnGordon and @adrtam. Thank you for all your helpful answers, I feel better now. By several lines of code such as `print -1 and False` outputs `False`, `print [] and False` outputs `[]`, `print None and False` outputs `None` and `print 0 and False` outputs `0`, I then know what is False equivalent and how to judge if an element is false equivalent or not, as @JohnGordon commented above.

Comment: @gery you can apply `bool` to something to see if it will evaluate to `True` or `False` e.g. `bool(None)`

Comment: @gmds Wow, it's really convenient. Cool!! Thank for such a neat method.

Answer (score 1):

for example:you can do this in Python Console

```
>>>a = None
>>>b = []
>>>c = [1]
>>>type(a)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>type(b)
<class 'list'>
>>>type(c)
<class 'list'>
```

b and c have the same type list, and a belongs to 'NoneType'

b is an empty list ,there no elements in b, None is an special Object in Python, you see the boolean value(False =0, True =1),

```
>>>b is None
>>> False
>>>len(b) 
>>> 0

>>>if b is not None:
       print(b)
   else:
       print(b,"is None")
>>>[]  #(b is empty, but it's not None)
```

you can also do this :

```
>>>b.append(a)
>>>b
>>>[None]
>>>len(b)
>>>1  #(b have one element None)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is very kind of you.